# Not able to get response from NodeJs server express

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Hello again everyone.** i am  calling get method from front-end java-script whenever that page loads. The problem is i am not getting the response of that get request in my web page JavaScript. I am calling the getChats method whenever chatroom.hbs loads to show all the existing chats in the chatroom to that user but it's seems like  i am not getting the response from the server against that request. These are the files in my project

chatroom.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var obj = require('../bin/www');
var db = require('../databaseModels');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/:uName', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('chatroom', {title: 'Welcome to Chat Room', userName: 
  req.params.uName});
});

// save a new chat message in database
router.post("/putChats", async (req, res) => {
try {
  var chat = new db.Chats(req.body)
  await chat.save()
  res.sendStatus(200)
  //Emit the event
  obj.io.emit("chat", req.body)
} 
catch (error) {
  res.sendStatus(500)
  console.error(error)
}
})

// Get chat messages from detabase and return to client
router.get("/getChats", (req, res) => {
  db.Chats.find({}, (error, chats) => {
  res.send(chats)
})
})

// clear method for clearing the chats
router.post("/clear", function(){
// Remove all chats from collection
   db.Chats.remove({}, function(){
   obj.io.emit('cleared');
 });
})

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var chatroomRouter = require('./routes/chatroom');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/'}))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/chatroom', chatroomRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

chatroom.hbs

```
    <script>
    var socket = io()
    socket.connect('http://192.168.34.54:4747');
    socket.on("chat", addChat)
    $(() => {
        getChats()
        textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                    if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey == false){
                        // Emit to server input
                        if( $('#username').val() != '')
                        {
                            var chatMessage = {
                                name: $("#username").val(), chat: $("#textarea").val()
                            }
                            postChat(chatMessage)
                            var obj = document.getElementById('textarea');
                            obj.value = '';
                        }
                        else{
                            alert('Plear enter name of the sender!!!!');
                        }
                    }
                })
    })

    function postChat(chat) {
        $.post("http://192.168.34.54:4747/chatroom/putChats", chat)
    }

    function getChats() {
        $.get("http://192.168.34.54:4747/chatroom/getChats", (chats) => {
            chats.forEach(addChat)
        })
    }

    function addChat(chatObj) {
        var message = document.getElementById('messages');
        message.value +=  "\n" + chatObj.name+": "+chatObj.chat;
    }

    socket.on('cleared', function(){
        var message = document.getElementById('messages');
        message.value = '';
    });

    // Handle Chat Clear
    clear.addEventListener('click', function(){
        $.post("http://192.168.34.54:4747/chatroom/clear")
    });

    function myFunction() {
        // Get the snackbar DIV
        var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");

        // Add the "show" class to DIV
        x.className = "show";

        // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
        setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
    }
    (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        myFunction();
    });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Please try to log `chats` variable in `$.get("http://192.168.34.54:4747/chatroom/getChats", (chats) => {
            chats.forEach(addChat)
        })`

Comment: i tried and i am getting undefined there

Comment: Never Mind I found the mistake :)

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind I found the mistake :)

```
<script>
    var socket = io()
    socket.on("chat", addChat)
    $(() => {
        getChats()
        textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
                    if(event.which === 13 && event.shiftKey == false){
                        // Emit to server input
                        if( $('#username').val() != '')
                        {
                            var chatMessage = {
                                name: $("#username").val(), chat: $("#textarea").val()
                            }
                            postChat(chatMessage)
                            var obj = document.getElementById('textarea');
                            obj.value = '';
                        }
                        else{
                            alert('Plear enter name of the sender!!!!');
                        }
                    }
                })
    })

    function postChat(chat) {
        $.post("http://192.168.34.54:3111/chats", chat)
    }

    function getChats() {
        $.get("/chats", (chats) => {
            chats.forEach(addChat)
        })
    }

    function addChat(chatObj) {
        var message = document.getElementById('messages');
        message.value +=  "\n" + chatObj.name+": "+chatObj.chat;
    }

    socket.on('cleared', function(){
        var message = document.getElementById('messages');
        message.value = '';
    });

    // Handle Chat Clear
    clear.addEventListener('click', function(){
        $.post("http://192.168.34.54:3111/clear")
    });

</script>
```